# C++ Service - Simulate User Login

Tags: c++, winapi, service, authentication

I've got a service running on all the computers in my lab, and need to be able to simultaneously log on to all the computers.

All the computers have the same username, so that's not a problem.
But I'm having trouble finding a way to programmatically initiate the logon. I've read about `LogonUser()` and its counterparts, but they don't seem to have the functionality I need.
Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could do this from a c++ service?

Comment: So you mean the same effect as someone sitting before the computer logging in with keyboard/mouse/screen?

Comment: @deviantfan Yep, that's right

Comment: Why do you need this? A service by itself cannot programmably login to an interactive desktop on the local Workstation. The WinLogon screen (what the user logs into) runs on a secure desktop that cannot be accessed across sessions (for obvious security reasons). A service can login to a user account when it needs to impersonate that user to access securable objects (files, registry, pipes, etc).

Comment: That being said, there are third-party apps floating around that can "unlock" a local workstation (or a remote workstation if you use something like psexec), you can launch one of those apps from your service.  Or, you can try writing a custom [GINA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380543.aspx) (or whatever Microsoft replaced GINA with in Vista) to perform the actual login and then have the service trigger the GINA/whatever when needed, such as with `SendSAS()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : Why? Because every morning when I need to log on to all the computers, it's a pain to go around to each individual one and enter the password and log on. I've got spare time to code and no reason not to try to make my life a little easier. I'm trying **not** to have to use dll injection, but if I don't find an answer here that's what I'm gonna end up doing.

Comment: What makes you think DLL injection would work? You are trying to circumvent OS security. Why not just turn off the login altogether, or at least set the PCs to [auto-login](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872306.aspx)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau : I know DLL injection would work because it's what I'm using right now. The service finds the winlogon process, injects a mini-DLL that just uses `sendInput()` to enter the password and press Enter, and it works fine. But, that feels a little messy and if there's a better way to do it, I'd really like to learn how. Auto-login isn't an option right now, as my IT guy would kill me if I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only straightforward, supported way to do this is to use the autologon functionality.  The main disadvantage is that it requires rebooting the machines.

Here's the code I use (note that our account domain "scms" is hardcoded, so you'll need to change that bit):

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601

#include <windows.h>
#include <Ntsecapi.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

void setAutologon(void);

void clearAutologon(void);

WCHAR username[128];
WCHAR password[128];

int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
    if (argc == 2 && _stricmp(argv[1], "-clear") == 0)
    {
        clearAutologon();
        return 0;
    }

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Syntax: autologon username password\n");
        return 1;
    }

    swprintf_s(username, _countof(username), L"%hs", argv[1]);
    swprintf_s(password, _countof(password), L"%hs", argv[2]);
    setAutologon();
    return 0;
}

void fail(char * errmsg, DWORD err) 
{
    // Oops.  It didn't work.
    printf(errmsg, err);
    if (err == 0) err = 1;
    exit(err);
}

void storePassword(BOOL store_password) 
{
    LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES loa;

    LSA_HANDLE lh;

    LSA_UNICODE_STRING name;
    static const wchar_t name_buffer[] = L"DefaultPassword";

    LSA_UNICODE_STRING data;

    DWORD dw;

    loa.Length = sizeof(loa);
    loa.RootDirectory = NULL;
    loa.ObjectName = NULL;
    loa.Attributes = 0;
    loa.SecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    loa.SecurityQualityOfService = NULL;

    if ((dw = LsaOpenPolicy(NULL, &loa, POLICY_CREATE_SECRET, &lh)) != 0) fail("Error %u opening LSA policy.", LsaNtStatusToWinError(dw));

    name.Buffer = (wchar_t *)name_buffer;
    name.MaximumLength = name.Length = sizeof(name_buffer) - sizeof(*name_buffer);

    if (!store_password) 
    {
        if ((dw = LsaStorePrivateData(lh, &name, NULL)) != 0) fail("Error %u clearing stored password.", LsaNtStatusToWinError(dw));
        return;
    }

    data.Buffer = password;
    data.MaximumLength = data.Length = wcslen(password) * sizeof(*password);

    if ((dw = LsaStorePrivateData(lh, &name, &data)) != 0) fail("Error %u storing password.", LsaNtStatusToWinError(dw));

    LsaClose(lh);

    return;

}

void setAutologon() 
{
    LONG i;
    HKEY h;

    i = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon", 0, KEY_WOW64_64KEY | KEY_SET_VALUE, &h);
    if (i != ERROR_SUCCESS) fail("Unable to open Winlogon subkey (error %u).", i);

    i = RegSetValueEx(h, L"DefaultUserName", 0, REG_SZ, (CONST BYTE *)username, (wcslen(username)+1)*2);
    if (i != ERROR_SUCCESS) fail("Unable to set default logon user name (error %u).", i);

    storePassword(TRUE);

    i = RegSetValueEx(h, L"DefaultDomainName", 0, REG_SZ, (CONST BYTE *)L"scms", 10);
    if (i != ERROR_SUCCESS) fail("Unable to set default domain name (error %u).", i);

    i = RegSetValueEx(h, L"AutoAdminLogon", 0, REG_SZ, (CONST BYTE *)L"1", 2);
    if (i != ERROR_SUCCESS) fail("Unable to set automatic logon flag (error %u).", i);

    i = RegSetValueEx(h, L"ForceAutoLogon", 0, REG_SZ, (CONST BYTE *)L"1", 2);
    if (i != ERROR_SUCCESS) fail("Unable to set forced automatic logon flag (error %u).", i);
}

void clearAutologon(void) 
{
    LONG i;
    HKEY h;

    i = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon", 0, KEY_WOW64_64KEY | KEY_SET_VALUE, &h);
    if (i != ERROR_SUCCESS) fail("Unable to open Winlogon subkey (error %u).", i);

    i = RegSetValueEx(h, L"DefaultUserName", 0, REG_SZ, "", 1);
    if (i != ERROR_SUCCESS) fail("Unable to set default logon user name (error %u).", i);

    storePassword(FALSE);

    // In case the automatic logon was set by the previous version of rpwd or by
    // some other means, we clear the registry setting for DefaultPassword as well.

    i = RegDeleteValue(h, L"DefaultPassword");
    if (i != ERROR_SUCCESS && i != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) fail("Unable to remove default logon password (error %u).", i);

    i = RegDeleteValue(h, L"ForceAutoLogon");
    if (i != ERROR_SUCCESS && i != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) fail("Unable to remove force logon flag (error %u).", i);

    i = RegSetValueEx(h, L"AutoAdminLogon", 0, REG_SZ, (CONST BYTE *)"0", 2);
    if (i != ERROR_SUCCESS) fail("Unable to clear automatic logon flag (error %u).", i);
}
```

I use `psexec` (available from the MS web site) to run the code on all of the lab machines, and `psshutdown` (ditto) to reboot them.  Once they've started the logon process, you can clear the autologon.

No doubt you could adapt the same approach into a service easily enough.

If you want to avoid the reboot, you would need to [implement a credential provider](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404303(v=ws.10).aspx).  The last time I looked into this the documentation was distressingly sparse, but this may have improved.  You might also be interested in [pGINA](http://pgina.org/), an open source credential provider that may be useful as an example.  (Or, for all I know, may already contain the functionality you want!)

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks like this is the approach I'll be stuck with after all, until I can dive into those references :)